# reference request support of derived tensor product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tensor-products, derived-functors, derived-categories

I currently am working on trying to compute some Hochschild cohomology of some scheme. However, I should be able to do it as soon as I know/have a reference for the following natural statement:

Let $X$ be a scheme and $F,G\in \mathcal{D}^b\left(X\right)$ then
$$\mathrm{supp}\left(F\otimes G\right)\subset \mathrm{supp} \left(F\right)\cap \mathrm{supp}\left(G\right)$$

where the tensor product is the left derived tensor product.

Answer (score 2):

Tensor products (derived) commute with pullbacks (also derived), i.e.,
$$
\phi^*(F \otimes G) \cong \phi^*F \otimes \phi^*G.
$$
Now, if $\phi$ is the embedding of the complement of the support of $F$, the RHS is zero, hence the LHS is zero. The same is true for the complement of the support of $G$, hence
$$
\mathrm{supp}(F \otimes G) \subset 
\mathrm{supp}(F) \cap \mathrm{supp}(G).
$$
On the other hand, if $\phi$ is the embedding of a point in $\mathrm{supp}(F) \cap \mathrm{supp}(G)$, the RHS is nonzero, hence the LHS is nonzero, hence
$$
\mathrm{supp}(F \otimes G) \supset 
\mathrm{supp}(F) \cap \mathrm{supp}(G).
$$

Comment: thank you very much, that is awesome!